# Asp.Net Mvc Angular On Hard Page Refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I just have started working on angular js . I have defined my routing as below

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/activityRegs",
    {
        templateUrl: "Controller/Action",
        controller: "activityController"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/searchActivity",
    {
        templateUrl: "Controller/Action2",
        controller: "activityController"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise(
    {
        redirectTo: "/"
    });
```

This is working pretty good . But if I press F5 to hard refresh the page it gives me resource not found which is pretty obvious . But I am not sure how I can handle this type of errors . If I am on Page2 and i hit F5 then I want my page2  to be refreshed instead of any error .r

Comment: just found that your templateUrl doesn't provide pure HTML pages. is it CSHTML? you have to refer to this link which will surely resolve your problem. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806500/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is likely to happen as you are having # tag there in URL. remove it. and make sure when you refresh your page, your MVC action is called properly through MVC routes. else part will be done by angular itself.

lets say,

My MVC route is defined to HomeController and Index method (default setting).

I have loaded ng-view/ui-view within index.cshtml.

Now when I refresh page with f5, "Home" controller and "Index" method are called (Default setting).

Comment: I just configured my routing with url route names and just ponted always to default Home/Index and it worked for me .

routes.MapRoute(
                           name: "ActivityRegistration", /// Route Name
                           url: "activityRegs", /// Url - requested url ---shd be same as angular route name..
                           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                       );